# Failed to read row 0 column 3730

Tags: java, android, cursor, spinner, adapter

This is my code:

```
dbAdapterdepartamento = new DBAdapterDepartamento(new Sqlitebbdd(
                getApplicationContext()));

        Cursor cdept=dbAdapterdepartamento.getAllDepartamentos();
        cdept.moveToFirst();


        while (cdept.isAfterLast() == false) {
          if (cdept.getFloat(cdept.getColumnIndex("_id")) == 0) {
              String title = cdept.getString(cdept.getColumnIndex("departamento"));
              Log.e("",""+title);
          }       
          cdept.moveToNext();
        }
        cdept.moveToNext();


        departamentoSpinnerAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                cdept,
                new String[] { Tablas.ColumnDEPARTAMENTO.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
                SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sp2.setAdapter(departamentoSpinnerAdapter);
        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

The cursor only has 28 rows and 2 columns, but they return a big number of columns every time. This is the error:

> Failed to read row 0, column 3730 from a CursorWindow which was 28
>   rows, 2 columns.

Comment: Post your DB structure and logcat..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your DB on

```
      String title = cdept.getString(cdept.getColumnIndex("departamento"));
```

For

> row 0 , column departamento

hold number 3730 , and actually your DB table Structure not have column with index 3730

So the problem that you have Bad value in table values , may be insert issue